# Are these sentences characteristic of a native speaker?

Tags: idiomatic-language

I found someone online who can help me in English, and I will teach him Persian. He said to me:

> Yes, I am a native speaker of (American) English and well educated in reading and writing. I would be happy **to help proofread a paper for you**.

He must be a native speaker, but are these natural sentences of a native and educated speaker? for example I doubt about the structure of the bold parts.

These are other messages from him:

> I have a bachelor's degree in computer science. My job is **improving online site search** for The Home Depot, so I **work on algorithms to understand language**. I read papers, but I don't usually do research at my job, unless it is a small project to research **how an algorithm performs**.

Comment: As all of these sentences are grammatical, to answer the question in your title, we have to solely depend on assumptions. That would render your main question "primarily opinion-based". Besides, with the observation of this glimpse of their fluency, I don't see why it should be a problem if they're *not* a native speaker.

Comment: The person you found is using English idiomatically.  It is quite common for a speaker of American English to say "my job is {gerund} the .." rather than "my job is to {infinitive} the .....". My job is painting cars. My job is to paint cars.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani So, if there is no grammar error, or the sentences are understandable, then I can assume he is a native. I sent it here just to know all the sentences sound well.

Comment: I would say those sentences come from an educated speaker. You can definitely find much worse out there on the wild internet. I don't understand why those phrases seem odd to you considering that you list computer science in your bio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native speaker, I could easily write the same sentences.

There is no way to tell. There is nothing in those short extracts that would determine the nature of the writers english language background.

Comment: I agree. These aren't the way I would write all of these, but there is no indication that the speaker is not native.